# How to correctly use values from textboxes in html pls help me

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wanted to use values from textboxes but failed so i tried with constant values and now I am getting a NAN error. I am showing my result in a label btw.

```
function myFunction() {
  var translength = 2400
  var transSpacing = 150
  var transEndOverhang = 75
  var transStartOverhang = 75

  var longLength = 6000
  var LongSpacing = 150
  var LongStartOverhang = 75
  var LongEndOverhang = 75

  if (transSpacing != 0)
    document.getElementById('longAmount').value = ((transLength - transStartOverhang - transEndOverhang) / transSpacing) + 1;
  document.getElementById('longAmount').innerHTML = document.getElementById('longAmount').value
  if (document.getElementById('longAmount').value > 0 && transStartOverhang + ((document.getElementById('longAmount').value - 1) * transSpacing) + transEndOverhang < transLength)
    document.getElementById('longAmount').value = longAmount + 1;
  document.getElementById('longAmount').innerHTML = document.getElementById('longAmount').value
}
```

Comment: Dump all values with`console.log` to see which value is invalid.

Comment: `document.getElementById('longAmount').value` returns a string, not a number. You are trying to compare it to a number with `> 0`, hence the `NaN` (Not a Number) error.

Comment: Unable to understand you problem, post html as well.

Comment: I am not used to working in javascript so i dont really understand how it works :/

Comment: i am using the innerHTML so that the label on my page changes to the result that i am trying to store in "longAmount", because i tried it using .value but that doesnt change anything on my page

Comment: transLength doesn't exist in your example + document.getElementById('longAmount').innerHTML = document.getElementById('longAmount').value doesn't mean anything. Is longAmount a div or an input? What does the html page look like?

Comment: longAmount is a label where i would like to display my result.

Comment: and i thought innerHTML was used to display something on your page so i wanted to show the value of longamount on my page by using innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `innerHTML` and `value` for the same id. If that id is a textbox you should use `.value`. Also, to convert strings (the text from the textarea) you can use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

```
// Here you're taking a bunch of variables and sets the textareas value
document.getElementById('longAmount').value = ((transLength - transStartOverhang - transEndOverhang) / transSpacing) + 1;

// Makes no sense (textarea doesn't have a innerHTML)
document.getElementById('longAmount').innerHTML = document.getElementById('longAmount').value;

// document.getElementById('longAmount').value is a string here
if (document.getElementById('longAmount').value > 0 && transStartOverhang + ((document.getElementById('longAmount').value - 1) * transSpacing) + transEndOverhang < transLength)
    document.getElementById('longAmount').value = longAmount + 1; // longAmount is undefined.

// Again, makes no sense.
document.getElementById('longAmount').innerHTML = document.getElementById('longAmount').value;
```

Comment: but if I use value the resultLabel won't change to the result

Comment: Can ju compose a minimal html example with inline js and show us?

Comment: what is inline js ? sorry but its my first time using javascript

Comment: Put the `<script>alert('Javascript code goes here');</script>` before the closing `</body>` tag and post the html.

Comment: i did this and nothing happened

Comment: is this normal or not ?

Comment: how ould u program my problem

Comment: I don't know what your problem is so its kind of hard to give you a proper solution. I need code.